# Wordpress - How to display author's last two weeks posts?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

In *author.php* I want show last two weeks posts published by the author.
looks pretty simple but can find answer in Google.

Comment: For reference, see [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/); specifically [Author Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#author-parameters) and [Date Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters).

Comment: Please check this answer [Display posts by month](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176168), I hope it helps you. In your case you need to set `date_query` argument parameter of the get_posts method. Here is a very good article about it [WordPress Date Query](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-date-query/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use wp_query with following arguments.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby'   => 'date',
    'author'    => $author_id,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '2 weeks ago'
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```